# Can I take images directly from Google for my affiliate site?

Tags: images, affiliate, google-image-search, licenses

I have an affiliate site and I am new on this platform. I want to add images into my site.

Can I take images from Google directly without changing anything for them?

Comment: No. That would be a copyright infringement.

Comment: @closetnoc Note that images shown by Google are not owned by Google. You may want to specify that this copyright infringement is not one from Google which already has had many discussions about whether they themselves were possibly infringing copyrights by having all those images on their servers!

Comment: @AlexisWilke Google is not infringing on copyright. Thumbnails come under the fair use doctrine. The one law suit had absolutely no merit. I know copyright fairly well having to deal with copyright and trademarks for 30 years. It was a by product of the work I did.

Comment: @AlexisWilke if I remember right, I discussed this in an answer somewhere. Cheers!!

Answer (score 10):

No, unless you do a search with the *correct license*.

When you do an image search, there is an option to select the license.

Go to Images. Enter a search term. You should see a **Tools** button toward the left side. Click on it. It becomes gray and a set of dropdowns appear toward the right side.

Click on **Usage Rights** and select your expected usage. **"Labeled for Reuse"** is probably want you want assuming your site is commercial.

Click on the image and double check that the image is indeed offered for commercial usage on the site where it is made available.

Searching that way you are not unlikely to find websites that have large collections of such images. For example: https://pixabay.com/

Note that in most cases those websites give you the choice of clicking on *other* images that will take you to a different site where images are not 
free.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely not.

There are a number of websites that do offer free images that can be used for commercial purposes.

CC Search will allow you to search a number of online venues for suitable images
https://search.creativecommons.org/

Comment: It should be noted that CC Search does provide for searching Google Images that are listed with a Creative Commons license. So this answer is technically correct in that you can't take images directly from Google without first checking their license, which can be done via that site, or by using Google's Image Search options.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good to take photos from google and then post it on your affiliate site. It is a big violation on trademark.

Comment: Trademark violations occur when you use names or logos.   I'm not sure why you think most images found in Google image search would lead do big trademark violations.